# Go Youtube API The field startWithSlate is required, startWithSlateRequired

Tags: go, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to update broadcast event with Go's [youtube data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/errors)

But it always show an Error if I set it to `false`: `The field startWithSlate is required, startWithSlateRequired` unless I set `startWithSlate` to `true` or remove the lib's [source code](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3) on `youtube/v3/youtube_gen.go` from

```
StartWithSlate bool `json:"startWithSlate,omitempty"`
```

to

```
StartWithSlate bool `json:"startWithSlate"`
```

Is there any other solution for this? or if this a bug, where can I send the bug report? since the site told me to [post on stackoverflow](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support).

Comment: I don't know "GO", but is it "Slate" or is it supposed to be "State" ? Just a thought.

Comment: it's a slate (meaning: cover)